# IPTABES & Docker - Why can I not connect to containerized PostgreSQL services?

Tags: iptables, docker, postgresql

I am learning how to implement iptables rules. I currently have the following rules:

```
#!/bin/sh

iptables -F

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m multiport --dports 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m multiport --sports 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT
```

The rules should be pretty easy to follow:

```
- Start from scratch
- Allow local traffic
- Allow incoming ssh, www traffic
- Allow outgoing www traffic
- Allow outgoing dns traffic
- Disallow all other traffic
```

Now I spawn a PostgreSQL server as following:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

I now want to connect in the host to that PostgreSQL container:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost
```

I am getting:

```
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
```

I am not getting this error when I don't implement the iptables rules as stated above.

I would have expected that Docker adds/removes rules on-the-fly when containers are started/removed, to allow access to open ports.

**iptables -S: rules after boot**

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION
-N DOCKER-USER
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m multiport --sports 53 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m multiport --dports 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

**iptables -S: rules after docker run postgres**

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION
-N DOCKER-USER
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m multiport --sports 53 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m multiport --dports 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

As you see in the third last line, a rule has been added to allow incoming 5432.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-i lo` means traffic over the *loopback* interface only. While Docker containers are "local", they *do not* use the loopback interface – they connect to the host using virtual Ethernet interfaces.

Since you don't have a rule allowing outgoing or incoming PostgreSQL traffic, it gets blocked.

Comment: Thank you! I understand that. But isn't Docker supposed to dynamically add/remove such rules when I start/stop the container? I am quite puzzled how to solve this, as I cannot know the IPs of the container in advance?

Comment: If Docker adds rules dynamically, then have you tried _looking at the live ruleset_ to make sure they're in there? Your post has no mention of that, and only talks about the original ruleset you've set up.

Comment: You are right, I should have added that to my question. I have done that now.

Comment: So as you can see, Docker _only_ adds forward rules (when your host is acting as a gateway), not input/output. So the above answer still applies. (This may actually be intentional, to protect the host from containers.)

Comment: I will have to studies to do, I am missing some understanding in these concepts. Thanks for pointing in this direction.